# Don't understand Hungerford Algebra proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

I found the following corollary in Hungerford:

[image]

I was able to produce a proof of my own for the most part, but I got stuck in the last statement: How does $f(N)=M$ and $Ker(f)\subset N$ give $f^{-1}(M)\subset N$? In fact, doesn't the first condition $f(N)=M$ give $N\subset f^{-1}(M)$, the exact opposite statement?

Comment: Hungerford uses $\subset$ to mean "is a subset" so $A\subset B$ is not "the exact opposite" of $B\subset A$ --they may both be true, as here.

Comment: If so, then the second part, $Ker(f)\subset N$ must provide $f^{-1}(M)\subset N$, which renders the first condition $f(N)=M$ redundant. What is the use of it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in f^{-1}(M)$, then $f(x)=m$ for some $m\in M$. But $f(N)=M$, so in fact $f(x)=f(n)$ for some $n\in N$. Hence $f(x-n)=f(x)-f(n)=0$ and so $x-n\in \ker f\subseteq N$. So $x-n=n'$ for some $n'\in N$. Hence $x=n+n'\in N$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I see.